# How to get comments from last week using PRAW?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm reading the [doc for `get_comments`](https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/code_overview.html#praw.objects.Redditor.get_comments) and I can't figure out what the correct input for the `time` parameter is. I know the default is "all", but do I input specific dates, or does it have to be words like "day", "week", etc?

Say I want to get comments a user made within the week, would it be something like:

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='blah')
user = r.get_redditor(username)
comments = user.get_comments(sort='new', time='week', limit=None)
```

Comment: The docs don't say as you note, but have you looked at the code or just tried it?

Comment: @Ben I have tried it. Using "week" or date format like "2014-01-01" don't seem to work. They both return the same result as "all".

Comment: I have submitted a pull request; the documentation now includes the valid parameter values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see in the [source code](https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/blob/master/praw/internal.py#L31) that the `time` parameter is passed to the API as `t`. According to the [Reddit API documentation](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_user_%7Busername%7D_%7Bwhere%7D):

> `t`: one of (`hour`, `day`, `week`, `month`, `year`, `all`)

Comment: `user.get_comments(time='all', limit=None)` and `user.get_comments(time='week', limit=None)` are giving me the same result, which unless I've made all 1000 comments in the past week, I'm guessing this is a PRAW bug.

Comment: @dee in that case, perhaps raise it via their https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues

Comment: In order to use `time` you must sort by either controversial or top. However, it looks like for user comments these listings haven't been generated: https://www.reddit.com/user/spladug/comments?sort=top&t=year